# Prolog predicate - returns list with duplicates removed from specific predicate

Tags: prolog, return-value

I'm a complete noob trying to write predicates and I've come a bit stuck. Earlier, I made a predicate called `remDuplicates/2` which would state true, if the 2nd list of the predicate, was the 1st list with any duplicates removed. Please see the code below for the predicate I'm using.

```
   remDuplicates([], []).
   remDuplicates([H|T], [H|T1]) :- subtract(T,[H],T2), remDuplicates(T2, T1).
```

However, now I'm trying to create a new predicate, that uses `remDuplicates` to remove duplication from a single list, called `remT/1`. `remT/1` that takes a single parameter, should use the `remDuplicates` predicate to remove any duplication, and then return the new list (without any duplication).

I've made an attempt as to how it should start but really, I have no idea where to go with it. Please see the start of my attempt below;

```
  remT([]).
  remT([H|T]) :- remDuplicates([H|T],[H|T]).
```

Would really appreciate help on this. Thanks.

Comment: There is normally no such thing as "returning" in Prolog, nor are there mutable variables. Why do you need such a predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Boris told you, in Prolog there is no such thing as "returning", however, you can call your `remDuplicates/2` like this:

```
remDuplicates([1,2,2,3,4,5,7,5], T).
```

This way, `T` will be the final list with no duplicates. You can then use it inside a bigger predicate or just run it on the terminal, since it will print on the screen something like `T = [1,2,3,4,5,7]`.

You can also check out the `sort/2` predicate, which has a similar result as yours, already built in to SWI-Prolog.

Hope it helped,
André Pinto

Comment: Hi @DrAntarctica - thanks for the advice. Is there anyway that I can use 'remT' predicate without having to insert a variable myself? (i.e. putting a variable into the 'remT' variable to be printed out, without the user having to do so - like my attempt below) ..

Comment: remT([]).
remT([H|T],X) :- remDuplicates([H|T],X).

Comment: You can have remT/1 like this: remT(List) :- remDuplicates(List, X), write('New List: '), write(X).
Edit: I don't know if I understood correctly, but feel free to clarify if I didn't get it right.